# How do I add another intent and how do I call this receiver in code?

Tags: android

I have following receiver that listens to Boot_Completed

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.ActionBootCompletedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I want to add another intent-filter with my own custom action. And make it private to my app if possible. This is mostly for code reuse so I can run same code path as when BOOT_COMPLETED.

So, I need following (if it's even possible)
1. intent-filter and make it private to my app
2. Code to send that intent so my receiver get's it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use another `<action>` tag! It is all you need to register receiver for an particular intent.

Comment: How do I call that BroadCastReceiver from my own code? And how do I pass that specific intent?

Comment: @katit through sendBroadcast() method. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29